# TouchUp evet does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am creating TouchUP and TouchDown event. In my case only TouchDown event is working but TouchUP is not working. why? How to fix?

```
 <telerik:RadTileList.Resources>
 <Style x:Key="itemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:Tile}">
 <EventSetter Event="TouchDown" Handler="Lvi_TouchDown"/>
 <EventSetter Event="TouchUp" Handler="Lvi_TouchUp"/>
 <Setter Property="telerik:Tile.Background" Value="Transparent" />
 <Setter Property="telerik:Tile.BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
 <Setter Property="telerik:Tile.BorderThickness" Value="0" />
 </Style>
</telerik:RadTileList.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to subscribe **PreviewTouchUp** event instead of **TouchUp** event

Comment: and selectionChanged item not working when we scrolling the item of tile. How to fix this?

Comment: PreviewTouchUp is an event.  Just replace Touchup with PreviewTouchUp and add an event handler for the same

Comment: Why cant you try Mouseup and MouseDown events?Why Touch events?  Mouse events will work for either mouse device or touch devices also

Comment: Actually  I have tile list  inside scroll viewer and when we selecting any tile  by touch then tile not selecting but tile scrolling is working very well. We need scroll item of tile by touch screen and also selection changed event of tile list. How to fix this?

Comment: for more details you can see my previous question. This is related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645666/selection-changed-of-tilelist-is-not-working-with-touch-scrolling